# parseInt function that takes number words as parameters

Tags: javascript

I need some help, my code works fine with three digits numbers, i need this working with seven digits numbers top. First split input, then iterates and compares with a dataBase variable.. im really stuck at this point. Input may or may not contain hyphen. Thanks in advance.

```js
function parseInt(string) {
  var output = [];
  var dataBase = {
    'zero': 0,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    'ten': 10,
    'eleven': 11,
    'twelve': 12,
    'thirteen': 13,
    'fourteen': 14,
    'fifteen': 15,
    'sixteen': 16,
    'seventeen': 17,
    'eighteen': 18,
    'nineteen': 19,
    'twenty': 20,
    'thirty': 30,
    'forty': 40,
    'fifty': 50,
    'sixty': 60,
    'seventy': 70,
    'eighty': 80,
    'ninety': 90,
    'hundred': 100,
    'thousand': 1000,
    'million': 1000000,
    'and': 0
  }

  var arr = string.split(" ");
  console.log(arr);

  var length = arr.length;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].includes("-")) {
      var index = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
      var hecta = arr[i].split('-');
      arr.splice(index, 1, hecta[0], hecta[1]);
    }
  }

  console.log(arr);

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    output.push(dataBase[arr[i]]);
  }

  console.log(output);

  var transform = 0;
  transform = output[0] * output[1] + output[2] + output[3];
  return transform;
}

console.log(parseInt('two hundred forty-six')); //246
console.log(parseInt("one hundred seventy-one")); //171
console.log(parseInt('one thousand two hundred and thirty')); // not works
```

Comment: I would look for a package to parse natural language numbers

Comment: For the one that doesn't work, look at how many elements are in your `output` variable. `[1, 1000, 2, 100, 0, 30]` that's 6. Now look at your line that calculates the final amount `transform = output[0] * output[1] + output[2] + output[3];` that's only expecting four values in the `output` array. Thoughts: reverse the array, remove the zero, and then iterate over your array. If any element of the reversed array is 100+ multiply it by the next element if the next element is less than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, your transform isn't doing what you want and you'll need to iterate over the whole array in reverse to use your current technique. So I refactored your code to demonstrate. What did I change?

I replaced variable names with what I would have used (naming is subjective but I prefer they be descriptive).

Next: String.split() can take a regular expression and be able to split on multiple different characters at a time. The regular expression `/[ -]/` just means split on any character that is either a space or a dash.

Then: Array.map() allows us to create a new array from an existing array by transforming each element using the function specified (in this case the function is looking up the integer from your word "database").

Finally we iterate over the array of numbers adding them into the final sum as appropriate.

```js
function parseInt(string) {
    const wordNumbers = {
      'zero': 0,
      'one': 1,
      'two': 2,
      'three': 3,
      'four': 4,
      'five': 5,
      'six': 6,
      'seven': 7,
      'eight': 8,
      'nine': 9,
      'ten': 10,
      'eleven': 11,
      'twelve': 12,
      'thirteen': 13,
      'fourteen': 14,
      'fifteen': 15,
      'sixteen': 16,
      'seventeen': 17,
      'eighteen': 18,
      'nineteen': 19,
      'twenty': 20,
      'thirty': 30,
      'forty': 40,
      'fifty': 50,
      'sixty': 60,
      'seventy': 70,
      'eighty': 80,
      'ninety': 90,
      'hundred': 100,
      'thousand': 1000,
      'million': 1000000,
      'and': 0
    }
  
    let words = string.split(/[ -]/);
    console.log(words);
    
    let numbers = words.map(word => wordNumbers[word]);
    numbers.reverse();
    console.log(numbers);
  
    let result = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] < 100) {
            result += numbers[i];
        }
        else {
            if(i + 2 < numbers.length && numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i] && numbers[i + 2] < numbers [i + 1]) {
                result += numbers[i] * numbers[i + 1] * numbers[i + 2];
                i++; i++;// need to skip the next two elements of ints in the for loop
            }
            else if(i + 1 < numbers.length && numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]) {
                result += numbers[i] * numbers[i + 1];
                i++; // need to skip the next element of ints in the for loop
            }
            else {
                result += numbers[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
  
  console.log(parseInt('two hundred forty-six')); //246
  console.log(parseInt("one hundred seventy-one")); //171
  console.log(parseInt('one thousand two hundred and thirty')); // 1230
  console.log(parseInt('twenty million')); // 20000000
  console.log(parseInt('two hundred thousand')); // 200000
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, i can read your code clearly. Something is wrong yet, if i input 'two hundred thousand' outputs 1200

Comment: Sure... instead of just checking if the next number in the reversed array is less than 10, we'll need to check the next two numbers to see if they are less than the current number and multiply by them. That would take care of that, I think. I updated my code and added a couple of new test cases.

Comment: I will leave it as an exercise to you to solve inputs such as "three hundred and twenty one million four hundred thirty three thousand seven hundred and eight" :)

Comment: we can also imagine counting with billions and more, which leads to the problem of integer representation overflow

Comment: JavaScript does have a BigInt class, but the Number class can hold a value up to 2**53 -1 (9,007,199,254,740,991). That's 9 quadrillion -- more than most people would try to express in words, I think. :)

Comment: I think I have solved this exercise in my new answer, it can even be easily adapted for quadrillion

Answer (score 2):

after reading the **mlibby** comments (with values in millons), I decide to start from scratch.
the result is really simpler!

I also added an interface to display the results in a more readable way

```js
const dataBase = 
      { zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4
      , five: 5, six: 6, seven: 7, eight: 8, nine: 9, ten: 10
      , eleven: 11, twelve: 12, thirteen: 13, fourteen: 14
      , fifteen: 15, sixteen: 16, seventeen: 17, eighteen: 18
      , nineteen: 19, twenty: 20, thirty: 30, forty: 40
      , fifty: 50, sixty: 60, seventy: 70, eighty: 80, ninety: 90
      , hundred: 100, thousand: 1000, million: 1000000, and: 0
      } 

const parseVal=s=>
        s.match(/\w+/g)
         .reduce((tots,sVal)=>
          {
          let n = tots.length -1
          switch (sVal) {
            case 'hundred':
                    tots[n] *= 100
                    break
            case 'thousand':
            case 'million':
                    tots[n] *= dataBase[sVal]
                    tots.push(0)
                    break
            default:
                    tots[n] += dataBase[sVal]
                    break;
            }
          return tots
          },[0]).reduce((a,c)=>a+c);


// testing part...

const myTable = document.getElementById('my-table')

for(let r=1;r<myTable.rows.length;++r )
  {
  let rowCell = myTable.rows[r].cells
  rowCell[1].textContent = parseVal(rowCell[0].textContent).toLocaleString('en')
  if (rowCell[1].textContent === rowCell[3].textContent)
    {
    rowCell[2].textContent = 'OK'
    rowCell[2].className = 'isOK'
    }
  else
    {
    rowCell[2].textContent = 'bad'
    rowCell[2].className = 'isBad'
    }
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  }
thead {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  }
tbody {
  background-color: #e1e7ee;
  }
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .3em .7em;
  }
td:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: right;
  }
td:nth-child(3) { text-align: center; }
td.isOK { color:green }
td.isBad { color:red }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>text value</td> <td>Parsed</td> <td>validation</td><td>expected</td> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>two hundred forty-six</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>246</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>two hundred thousand</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>200,000</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>two hundred thousand and twelve</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>200,012</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one hundred seventy-one</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>171</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>one thousand two hundred and thirty</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>1,230</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>three hundred and twenty one million four hundred thirty three thousand seven hundred and eight</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>321,433,708</td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, im trying to understand your code, im learning javascript since a few months

Comment: @sonEtLumiere, I changed everything and it OK for `three hundred and twenty one million four hundred thirty three thousand seven hundred and eight` or more with minor changes

Answer (score 0):

This works for entries such as two hundred thousand...

```js
function parseInt(string) {
  var output = [];
  var dataBase = {
    'zero': 0,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    'ten': 10,
    'eleven': 11,
    'twelve': 12,
    'thirteen': 13,
    'fourteen': 14,
    'fifteen': 15,
    'sixteen': 16,
    'seventeen': 17,
    'eighteen': 18,
    'nineteen': 19,
    'twenty': 20,
    'thirty': 30,
    'forty': 40,
    'fifty': 50,
    'sixty': 60,
    'seventy': 70,
    'eighty': 80,
    'ninety': 90,
    'hundred': 100,
    'thousand': 1000,
    'million': 1000000,
    'and': 0
  }
   let clarray=[]
   filteroutp=[]
   fo=[]
   var f
   var acc=[]
   var res=0
    const strarray= string.split(' ')
    strarray.forEach((n,i)=>{
      if(n.includes('-')) { 
        nm=n.split('-'), clarray.push(...nm)
      }   
      else clarray.push(n)
    })
      Object.entries(dataBase).forEach(o=>{
    clarray.forEach((x,i)=>{if (x==o[0]) output[i]=o[1] })})
     if(output[output.length-1]&&output[output.length-2]<100&&output.length-2!=0){
      n=output.pop() , f=output.pop()+n
     }
     else f=0
         for(let i=0;i<output.length;i++){
          n=output[i]
          m= output[i+1]
          if(m=="undefined") m=1
          if(output.length>1){
            if(n<m ){
          if(acc.length!=0){
           accn= acc.shift()
            accn<n? fo.push(accn*n*m):fo.push(accn+n*m)
            output.splice(i,2)
            i=-2
            }        
          else if(acc.length==0) {
            acc.push(n*m)
              if(output.length>1){
               output.splice(i,2)
               i=-2 
              }
              if(output.length==1){
                fo.push(acc.shift()*output[0])
                output.splice(0,1)
                 i=-1
              }
            }
          }
      }
      if(output.length==0&&acc.length!=0) fo.push(acc.shift())
    } 
      fo.push(f)
      for(let n of fo){
        res+=n
      }
   
  return "output "+`${fo}` + " number "+res

}

console.log(parseInt('two hundred forty-six')); //246
console.log(parseInt("one hundred seventy-one")); //171
console.log(parseInt('one thousand two hundred and thirty')); //1230
console.log(parseInt('one million one thousand two hundred and thirty')); // 1001230
console.log(parseInt('ten million one-thousand two hundred and thirty-two')); // 10001232
console.log(parseInt('one thousand seventeen hundred and thirty')); // 2730
console.log(parseInt('two hundred thousand')) //200000
```